# How to include the question number to the gradetable in an exam?

Tags: exam, gradetable

For an exam, each problem is named. So I would like to include the question in the grade table including question number and name left-aligned.

With the following example, the questions are centred and the question number is not included. How can I do this? Ideally, I would like to show `1. What's the difference between a duck?` in the grade table.

Here is the code :

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\qformat{
  \large\textbf{Question \thequestion~: \thequestiontitle}
  \quad (\thepoints)\hfill
  \vrule depth 1em width 0pt
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \gradetable[v][questions]
\end{center}

\begin{questions}
    \titledquestion{What's the difference between a duck?}[42]
    Lorem ipsum.
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following lines after loading the document class.

```
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd*\@multicolumntable{|c|c|c|c}{|l|c|c|c}{}{}
\xpatchcmd\questions{\def\@currentlabel{\thequestiontitle}}{\def\@currentlabel{\thequestion. \thequestiontitle}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd*\@multicolumntable{|c|c|c|c}{|l|c|c|c}{}{}
\xpatchcmd\questions{\def\@currentlabel{\thequestiontitle}}{\def\@currentlabel{\thequestion. \thequestiontitle}}{}{}
\makeatother

\qformat{
  \large\textbf{Question \thequestion~: \thequestiontitle}
  \quad (\thepoints)\hfill
  \vrule depth 1em width 0pt
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \gradetable[v][questions]
\end{center}

\begin{questions}
    \titledquestion{What's the difference between a duck?}[42]
    Lorem ipsum.
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How do you learn about this magic? I've read the manual and didn't find anything about that. How do you know you need to use xpatchcmd?

Comment: I have the error `\xshowcmd already defined!` when including `regexpatch`

Comment: Regarding the error: Start from my code above and add the `\usepackage` commands as well as the other code of your preamble step by step and test each time, whether the error occurs. Apparently some part of you preamble already loads `regexpatch` or `xpatch`.

Comment: Regarding the magic: `(rege)xpatch` is only a tool to patch macros. The command `\xpatchcmd` takes the name of a macro (`\@multicolumntable` and `\questions` above) and replace in its code one fragment by another one. The tricky part is to find the right patch. For this, I read the code of the package or class (here: `exam.cls`), try to understand the functionality, and then hopefully find a way to tweak the code such it does what we want.

Comment: @nowox If you don't want to/can't identiy the source of the problem, you can add the line `\let\xshowcmd\undefined` after my lines above. `\xshowcmd` is defined in the package `regexpatch`, but none of its commands are needed after performing the two `\xpatchcmd`, so it is safe to undefine any conflicting macro. But of course the cleaner way would be to find the conflict and avoid loading the package twice.

Comment: I found the problem. I was already using xpatch for xpretocmd. Since it is also included with regexxpatch it is now fine.